# checking if a file has 3 words per line unix

Tags: bash, file, unix, format, output

Hey guys so I'm trying to check if a file contains 3 words per line with only one space in between each word. There can't be any spaces before or after each line. Also it doesn't matter how many lines the txt file has. Then if the file has a bad format it outputs "Bad file format following lines were formatted incorrectly" and it outputs the bad lines.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Great idea, I think you missed the part in which you show what you have tried so far.

Comment: sorry I'm new to unix not sure what commands to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over the lines in the file and check that each line matches your requirements by using a regex.

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line
do
   if [[ ! $line =~ ^[^[:space:]]+\ [^[:space:]]+\ [^[:space:]]+$ ]]
   then
       echo "invalid line: $line"
   fi
done < file
```

It prints out each line which is invalid.

`^[^[:space:]]+\ [^[:space:]]+\ [^[:space:]]+$` is a regex which matches three words with only one space in between each word and no spaces at the start or end of the line.

Answer (score 2):

You can say:

```
diff inputfile <(awk 'NF==3' inputfile) || echo "Bad format"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this way:

```
if [ $(sed '/^[ ]\?\(\([a-zA-Z_]\+ \)\{2\}[a-zA-Z_]\+\)/d' a.txt | wc -l) != 0 ] ; then
    echo "error in file"
    exit 1
fi
```

It utilizes sed to remove all lines which are ok. If after that the file size isn't `0` there must been errors in the file.

Comment: Note that the `-F' '` is not necessary. Also, it does not check if there are two or more spaces in between fields.

Comment: @fedorqui yeah you are right.. seems I was too fast

Comment: ... preparing alternative

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
awk 'NF!=3{bad[k++]=$0} 
     END{print "Bad file format following lines were formatted incorrectly:";
         for (i in bad){print i}}' file
```